# Devel::Cover Branch coverage on conditional ternary operator

Tags: perl, devel-cover

I'm running `cover` from `Devel::Cover` on a module and getting 50% of branch coverage in lines that use the conditional ternary operator i.e.

`return @rgb ? map { hex $_ } @rgb : undef;`

Is this OK? Do I have to change the code to use `if/else` blocks in order to gain the 100% of coverage?

I'm new to `Devel::Cover` so any insight that you could provide about this, will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to return `undef` if `@rgb` is empty?  Wouldn't a return value of an empty list indicate the same thing?

Comment: 1. Switching to an `if` statement is not going to increase your coverage. 2. I'm guessing from what little is revealed from what you are doing, but It seems to me that returning an empty list would make far more sense than retuning undef. (`return map hex, @rgb;`)  3. Note that while making that change will claim 100% coverage, there's still a case you don't test.

Comment: If I change the procedure to return an empty list, I keep getting the 50% of coverage. Do you think of another reason of why I might be getting this score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not getting coverage for the *false* branch of the ternary, because your tests do not cover a case where `@rgb` is empty. In that case, the `map` will never be called, but it will return `undef` (or `()` like @ikegami suggested).

The ternary is the same as this:

```
if (@rgb) { 
  return map { hex $_ } @rgb;
} else {
  return undef;
}
```

So there is a branch there that has not been covered by the test.

You have several options:

- go with the empty list and just remove the ternary like ikegami suggested, and take into account that you don't ensure the program does what you want if `@rgb` has no elements
- add an `# uncoverable branch false` comment as described in https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover#UNCOVERABLE-CRITERIA
- write a test case where it expects `@rgb` not to have elements

  ```
  is foo('no_rgbs'), undef, 'returns undef when there are no elements';
  ```